# Compare two list and print matching items in same index Python

Tags: python

I have two lists and I have to print **only the items which are equal in the same index**.
These two lists have the same length. The only difference is that the second list, contains a list inside

**FIRST LIST**

`[['PRON', 'PART', 'CCONJ', 'PRON', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'ADP', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT'],[...]]`

**SECOND LIST**

`[['VERB', 'ADV', 'ADV', 'PRON', 'DET', 'PRON', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'VERB', 'PUNCT', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT'],[...]]`

I'd like to count how many items matches in the same position:

E.g.

Compare first_list[1,1] with second_list[1,1], first_list[1,2] with second_list[1,2]
So: *first_list[1,1] = 'PRON', second_list[1,1] = 'VERB', first_list[1,2]= 'PART', second_list[1,2]='ADV'*

This is what I've tried so far:

```
for inside_item_1, inside_item_2 in first_list, second_list:
         if inside_item_1 == inside_item_2 :
            count_correct_tag += 1
```

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using zip requires no length checks or variable initialization:

```
y = [['VERB', 'ADV', 'ADV', 'PRON', 'DET', 'PRON', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'VERB', 'PUNCT', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT'],['horse', 'dog', 'mouse']]
x = [['PRON', 'PART', 'CCONJ', 'PRON', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'ADP', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT'], ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']]

for a, b in zip(x,y):
  for c in zip(a, b):
    if c[0] == c[1]:
      print(c[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward to me.

```
count = 0
min_len = min(len(list1), len(list2))
for i in range(min_len):
     min_inner_len = min(len(list1[i]), len(list2[i])
     for j in range(min_inner_len):
          if list1[i][j] == list2[i][j]: count += 1
```

Alternatively, you could save the values in a 3rd list.

Edit:

min_len is uneccessary if the lists will always be the same length, just use the length of one of the lists. Also, if the elements of the top-level list can be individual variables and not other lists then that's something you need to account for.

```
if type(list1[i]) is list and type(list2[i]) is list:
     min_inner_len = min(len(list1[i]), len(list2[i])
     for j in range(min_inner_len):
          if list1[i][j] == list2[i][j]: count += 1
elif list1[i] == list2[i]: count += 1
```

Comment: OP says that the two lists have the same length, so min_len seems unnecessary

Comment: You're right, I missed that. Still worth thinking about, but if the lists will always be the same length then it's just extra complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This uses indexing to check for elements which are equal in the same position.

```
x = [['VERB', 'ADV', 'ADV', 'PRON', 'DET', 'PRON', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'VERB', 'PUNCT', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT']]
y = [['PRON', 'PART', 'CCONJ', 'PRON', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'ADP', 'DET', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'PUNCT']]
correct = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[0][i] == y[0][i]:correct +=1
print(f'similar elements {correct}')
```

Comment: Why? PRON in the 4th position is equal, so it's impossible to be zero

Comment: Oh wait my bad I changed it,

Comment: It doesn't work your code